# How to check whether ng-content exists

Tags: angular, transclusion

Suppose i have simple Bootstrap panel component with multiple transclusion slots. Template example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <ng-content select="my-panel-heading"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ng-content select="my-panel-content"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make panel-heading optional. How do i hide `<div class="panel-heading">` element, if there is no content provided for `<ng-content select="my-panel-heading"></ng-content>`

Comment: `ngIf` should be preferred over `[hidden]`. Is there a reason you prefer `hidden`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if variable showHeading is initialized to false, element is removed from template by the time ngAfterContentInit is called, making reference to viewChild undefined. If ngIf is prefered, you could change default value for showHeading to true and it should work.

Comment: Actually, i just tested it and it didnt work well with *ngIf even after changing default value to true. Reference to #panelHeading was still undefined cause *ngIf removed it.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Good catch.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have a parent element of `<ng-content>` with a template variable (`#panelHeading`)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" #panelHeading [hidden]="!showHeading">
    <ng-content select="my-panel-heading"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ng-content select="my-panel-content"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

then you can query for it like

```
@ViewChild('panelHeading') panelHeading;
```

and set a property depending on whether there are children or not

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

showHeading:boolean = false;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.showHeading = this.panelHeading.nativeElement && this.panelHeading.nativeElement.children.length > 0;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

If `<my-panel-heading>` is an Angular2 component, then you can also use

```
@ContentChild(MyPanelHeading) panelHeading:MyPanelHeading;

constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

showHeading:boolean = false;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.showHeading = this.panelHeading != null;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: By setting showHeading default value to 'false', this.panelHeading is 'undefined'. By setting showHeading default value to 'true', it works correctly but I get 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError' in console. Moreover, I have to use 'ngAfterViewInit' instead of 'ngAfterContentInit', otherwise showHeading is always undefined. Any ideas how to solve? Thx

Comment: @Luca, thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer. I think now `ngAfterViewInit` is correct. I updated a few more things that should address the issues you mentioned.

Comment: thank you! For my solution I preferred the use of `*ngIf` instead of `hidden` by setting `showHeading` default value to true. Now all works correctly :)

Comment: Ok, I assume that's the reason why you got `undefined`. `*ngIf` actually removes the content from the DOM, while `hidden` only hides it and `@ContentChild()` still can find it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, what is the purpose of the ChangeDetectorRef in this situation?

Comment: There are some lifecycle callbacks where it results in an exception ("The model has changed after it was checked" or similar) when the model is changed in this callback. Calling `detectChanges` fixes this exception.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tested it now and received that error.  And adding ChangeDetectorRef fixed it.
Also, I had to set showHeading initially to true in order to make my component to work properly.

Answer (score 31):

You'd have to remove all your spaces but you could do this with CSS if you really cared about it (ng-content doesn't take up space):

```
.panel-heading:empty { display: none }

<div class="panel-heading"><ng-content select="my-panel-heading"></ng-content></div>
```

Comment: Great solution. Simple and efficient.

Comment: `:empty` is sweet! Thanks @William Neely.

Comment: This does not work anymore... Angular is adding some kind of \n to my div element in the latest releases.

Comment: @muuvmuuv what version?

Comment: Solved it. I accidentally had line breaks in a parent component which were inherited.

Comment: haha yes me too but sometimes it is just a cup of coffee and good sleep :D

Answer (score 4):

Do:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" [hidden]="!panelHeading.hasChildNodes()" #panelHeading>
    <ng-content select="my-panel-heading"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ng-content select="my-panel-content"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note you can't use `*ngIf` in this case, for catch-22 situation.

Comment: I do not work with Angular anymore, but this looks like the best answer (if it works)

Comment: Great solution. The hint about `*ngIf` is gold. Thank you very much !