# Is it possible to do conditional content projection (transclusion) in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I would like to provide default content that would appear only if content is not transcluded.

For example Here is my component template:

```
<article>
    <header>
        <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
    </header>
    <section>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </section>
</article>
```

I can use it like this:

```
<my-component>
    <h1 header>This is my header</h1>
    <p>This is my content</p>
</my-component>
```

Now what if i wanted to provide a default header. Is it possible; without acrobatics like checking for content in `ngAfterContentInit`?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38692980/373655 . Not sure if a more elegant solution exists that doesn't require `ngAfterContentInit`

Comment: Also, can you alias a projection? `<ng-content class=".for-parent" select=".for-me">`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with pure CSS!
Imagine you have the following

```
<ng-content select=".header"></ng-content>
<h1 class="default-header">
     This is my default header
</h1>
```

then the following CSS would hide the header if the content is supplied:

```
.header + .default-header {
    display: none;
}
```

If no header is supplied, then the display:none rule isn't matched.

Note, you'll have to turn off content encapsulation to use this: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

Comment: Clever, I never think of sibling selectors for some reason. (maybe I'm too old school?)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You should configure that component to accept an ng-template element that contains the content you want to conditionally render.

For more info https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#conditional-content-projection