# Conditional template slot in ng-template

Tags: angular, templates, angular-template

Is there a way to conditionally show slots in an angular template? I want to transclude content, if there is any, and show default content otherwise.

Let's say there's a `my-card` component, with a template like this:

```
<my-card>
  <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
  <div *ngIf="!card-body">Default text</div>
</my-card>
```

Then the usage (in, say, app component) would be like this:

```
<!-- This will show the card body -->
<my-card><div card-body>This is card body</div></my-card>
<!-- This will show the default text -->
<my-card></my-card>
```

If this won't work with slots, what are my alternatives?

Comment: Apparently, CSS will do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832199/is-it-possible-to-do-conditional-content-projection-transclusion-in-angular-2. I'm curious though if there are other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive with selector `card-body`.

```
@Directive({selector: '[card-body]'})
export class CardBodyDirective {
}
```

Then in `my-card` component, use it as follows

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-card',
  template: `
    <div class="card">
      <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>
      <div *ngIf="!cardBody">Default text</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyCardComponent  {
  @ContentChild(CardBodyDirective) cardBody;

}
```

Do not forget to declare `CardBodyDirective` and export in the same module.

You can take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bf5vjh?file=app/my-comp.component.ts)

Comment: I took a variation of this to make my thing work. I didn't put all of the problem in my question as it seemed irrelevant, but I actually want to pass nested selector further as another nested selector.

Comment: Can you elaborate little further? I might be help. I just didn't quite understand your last sentence.

Comment: Well, I tried to re-project content. Apparently, there is an ngProjectAs directive to help out with that.